# How can I enable the create button when publishing an azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create a digital twin using azure following this demo I found on YouTube. However, when I try to publish my function, the `create` button is disabled. [image: Here is an image of the window.] I am not sure if this is a problem with the subscription I currently have, I did the tutorial twice and the same thing happened. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you already created a function app using the portal? and what version did you use for the function app? 3.1? also see this documentation by Microsoft. Might help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/develop-test-deploy-azure-functions-with-visual-studio/

Comment: I was able to recreate the demo in the link and it worked. However, the problem still persists when I try to publish the function app.  The target framerwork is a `NetCore 3.1`, so the version should be at least 3.x.

Comment: Check if you have right RBAC Role such as contribution role to the Azure Functions Apps or Subscription?