# Publishing Azure Function using Visual Studio not possible: Create button disabled

Tags: azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

I want to publish an Azure Function Project using the Visual Studio 2022 publish option, but the `Create` button is always disabled without any visible reason for it:

[image]

How can I further research on this, get any error message or so?

Comment: As a workaround, could you try to create function app manually on Azure portal? Then you could download "Publish Profile", and use that to publish this function app from Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks for the hint, that indeed worked like a charm. Still wondering what's wrong with the assistant.

Comment: Not Sure, multiple time I too faced similar issue and haven't found any permanent solution to it. #[67813149](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67813149/16630138). After Sign-out and Sign-in, System Restart, I got this fixed but this should not be the fix.

Answer (score 4):

I got this to work by going to the Azure portal directly and first manually creating the three dependencies, ie:

- resource group
- storage account
- application insights

I could then return to this form (ie close and reopen it) and select those items I'd created, instead of using this form to create new ones.

Comment: Thanks, I've only created resource group and storage account before and it work, no problem with application insights

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Multiple times, Even I too faced the similar issue and haven’t found any permanent solution to it where I’m having the latest Version of Azure Functions Core Tools (`4.0.4915`), VS 2022 17.4.4 Version, .NET 6 SDK & Runtime installed.

I found the Similar SO issue where many users faced this issue #[67813149](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67813149/16630138).

I also found one of the causes of above issue - i.e., If we do not have access to the Azure Subscription, then I observed this **Create** button is **greyed** or **disabled** in the **Visual Studio Azure Functions** Project > **Publish** > **Create New Function App Window**.

[image]

Also, Please check you have right RBAC Access to manage the resources in the Subscription such as Contributor role for the Azure Function App Management. Visit this MS Q&A #[669276](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/669276/azure-function-rbac) for more information.

After Sign-out and Sign-in in Visual Studio, System Restart, I got this fixed and working good as of now, but this should not be the fix. If you are facing this issue frequently, mail to `azcommunity@microsoft.com`.